# Php Wordpress (is_rtl()) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'; add Multi-Languages

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, multilingual, wpml

I have this code for WordPress with WPML (but the theme was built with laravel-blade). I need to add `Chain Lang` (`zh-hans`), so how can I do that?

```php
$context['direction'] = (is_rtl()) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
$context['lang'] = (is_rtl()) ? 'ar' : 'en';
```

I need to write this (zh-hans with EN in LTR), how can I do that?

Also, `EN` is the defult... this code for `AR`, how can I add `zh-hans` lang to this code?

```php
/**
 *  Get Customizer Options
 */
public static function get_option($option, $type = '', $default = '') {
    $option_trans = (is_rtl()) ? $option.'_ar' : $option;

    $value = ($default == 'trans') ? get_theme_mod($option, '') : get_theme_mod($option_trans, '');

    if ($type === 'img') {
        $option_trans = (is_rtl()) ? $option.'_ar' : $option;

        $value = ($default == 'trans')
            ? wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_theme_mod($option_trans, ''), 'full')
            : wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_theme_mod($option, ''), $default);
    }

    if ($type === 'editor') {
        $value = wpautop(get_theme_mod($option_trans, $default));
    }

    if ($type === 'group') {
        $trans_value = get_theme_mod($option_trans, '');

        $value = ($default == 'trans') ? $trans_value : get_theme_mod($option, '');
    }

    return $value;
}

/**
 * Get Translation
 */
public static function get_trans($rtl, $ltr) {
    $value = (is_rtl()) ? $rtl : $ltr;

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nico,

The site is in both English and Arabic.
I would like to add the Chinese language
Stuck writing code and modifying it!!

I welcome any attempt to help

Comment: for Ex. 
(( (is_rtl()) ? 'ar' : 'en'.'zh-hans';  ))  this right? or this : (( (is_rtl()) ? 'ar' : 'en . zh-hans'; ))

Comment: Why on earth are you setting the language based on the result of `is_rtl()`? Once you add a third language there is no possible way for this code to work.

Comment: Hi @Sammitch, The website is wordpress but own programming / I think it's integrated with Larval.. it's a bit complicated.

I hope to find help writing the code.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.